# Auto Complete is Very slow my page is hanging at search time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

In Below you can see my code .  #proname is my text box . Page loading time i will call api and fill data into auto complete source property.
At text entering time it is very slow. beacuse in my table i have 20000 records. 
So please give me an alternative solution for this problem.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serverbase+"Site/GetModels",
        contentType: "application/json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        var src = data.map(function (element) {
            return element.name;
        });
        $("#proname").autocomplete({
            source: src
        });

    });
```

Comment: Don't have 20000 records on the frontend. Paginate the API. Debounce the autocomplete call.

Comment: How frequently those 20000 records get updated? Is it a dynamic table?

Comment: @AnandG no its a static table data directly   get from DB.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Boy With Silver Wings comment, you should probably paginate the response that way you only get back so many records rather than ALL records. This also heaps reduce server load, as well load time for the front end.

To answer your question, autocomplete is requiring for your ajax call to complete before it finishes the request. If you MUST get all results, store the results locally rather than doing an AJAX request everything.

Without knowing what your back-end runs on, I can't really provide you with an example of paginating your data :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid pulling the data in a single request and instead query the data based on the autocomplete request.  For instance, take a look at this example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
  <input id="birds">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
  Result:
  <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Described here:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote